# Assign value to variable when declared in mysql

Tags: mysql

Oracle used `:=` operator to assign value when variable is declared in procedure.

How we can assign value to this mysql variable

```
declare variable varchar(20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use set keyword after declared it

```
Set variable=value;
```

Or use default

```
declare variable varchar(20) default value;
```